# Webassembly fixup section size at the end of every section?

Tags: webassembly

When compiling wat to wasm emscripten gives me FIXUP sizes for every section. In the specification it never states that in the raw bytecode we have to include the section size at the end of every section. Im a bit confused here. Is it safe to lets say omit the FIXUPs or what is the reason behind it? The section size right after the section code is 0. I mean shouldnt you know the size before reading a section? doesnt make sense or does it? I feel like the order of the two section sizes should be reversed.

Would appreciate some insights.

```
0000029: 00                                        ; section code
000002a: 00                                        ; section size (guess)
000002b: 04                                        ; string length
000002c: 6e61 6d65                                name  ; custom section name
0000030: 01                                        ; function name type
0000031: 00                                        ; subsection size (guess)
0000032: 01                                        ; num functions
0000033: 00                                        ; function index
0000034: 06                                        ; string length
0000035: 6164 6454 776f                           test  ; func name 0
0000031: 09                                        ; FIXUP subsection size
000003b: 02                                        ; local name type
000003c: 00                                        ; subsection size (guess)
000003d: 01                                        ; num functions
000003e: 00                                        ; function index
000003f: 01                                        ; num locals
0000040: 00                                        ; local index
0000041: 00                                        ; string length
000003c: 05                                        ; FIXUP subsection size
000002a: 17                                        ; FIXUP section size
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the byte offsets on the left: all lines marked FIXUP refer to byte positions that where previously written as 0 and marked as "guesses".

Like other Wasm generators, Emscripten produces the binary in one pass, which means that it does not yet know section sizes when it has to produce them. So it writes 00 and back-patches them once the respective section is complete and its size known.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to force generated wasm code that is already patched? (so without 0 sizes and FIXUP bytes)?